# C#.Net Webservice error handling

Tags: c#, web-services, error-handling

I wrote following webservice, when project not found then I want that webservice method only return

```
<error> No Project Found </error>
```

and not any other thing.

```
Project GetProject(int Project_id)
{
   Project dmo = new Project();
   ProjectDAO dao = new ProjectDAO();
   dmo = dao.GetProject(Project_id);
   return dmo;
}
```

Comment: what does the dao.GetProject return if no project is found?

Comment: it throws exception when no project found, I want to catch that exception here and return its message to user

Answer (score 2):

your webservice returns a type of Project  the things that your are going to return is'nt
type of that class or serialized of it

Comment: Yes!  in case of any error I want to return object of CError clas

Comment: the function return type should be Deterministic

Comment: I came to simple solution that is throwing SoapException, helpful link http://forums.asp.net/t/1166652.aspx/1